# How to insert rows with NULL values to a DolphinDB table?

Tags: null, append, void, dolphindb

I want to insert a record to a table with columns “A”, “B”, and “C”. In this record, the “B” column contains a NULL value. When I used `table(12 as A, NULL as B, 13 as C)`, I encountered an error: `Not allowed to create void vector`. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the appropriate NULL value representation based on the data type of the “B“ column. For example:

If the “B“ column is of INT type, use `00i`:

```
table(12 as A, 00i as B, 13 as C)
```

If the “B“ column is of SYMBOL type, use `''`:

```
table(12 as A, '' as B, 13 as C)
```